# Disable border collapsing in this test case

Tags: html, css

If you check the following demo HTML, you will see there is an unexpected orange border at the top of the page in all browers (I checked).
If the <p> tag is replaced by a <div> tag, everything works like expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Test Lay-Out</title>         
        <style>
            html{
                overflow: auto; /*for IE*/
                height: 100%;
            }

            body{
                background-color: orange;
                margin: 0;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #page{
                background-color: green;

                height: 100%;
                margin-bottom: -50px;
            }
            #footer{
                background-color: red;
                height: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">footer</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is because the <p> has a top margin and through border collapsing gets collapsed to the parent element. While this is a desired effect for creating text paragraphs and such, it seldomly is usefull for lay-outs.
How can I make sure that borders aren't elevated to certain elements (in this case from the <p; to the parent div)?

**--UPDATE--**
Because the answers all seem to go down the "disable the padding on the paragraph" road, I reworked my question a bit and altered the title.
Removing the padding from the p is a way to remove the simptom, not the cause.

Answer (score 5):

the padding for body/html needs to be reset as well.

Answer (score 2):

The `<p>` element has a `margin-top` by default, which pushes the whole content down.  You can get rid of it using `margin-top: 0` on that `<p>`.

Comment: Indeed. I was answering my question while you did the same ;) But this isn't really solving the problem, just the simptoms.
While I can see how collapsing borders sometimes can be handy, I feel it should not be the default. I thought border-collapse: seperate would do the trick. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

All browsers load a default stylesheet before any styles you define.

This is the style you see when you load a "plain" HTML into your browser.

You should look into and use a [CSS reset](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=css+reset&meta=) in pretty much all your projects.

Comment: Thats fine, I wasn't really advocating a 3rd party reset. It's just a good way to avoid things like you describe above

Answer (score 0):

It is because `<p>` is block element and always starts in new line.
if you want your code to work with the `<p>` tag then add to you CSS

```
p
{
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: The new line is not the problem. That's because it's a block element. It's the collapsed top margin of the parent element I was worried about.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda lame, but I actually found it myself.
Once again it's the collapsing borders tricking me. [Here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3530816.htm) is a good forum post that describes it.
In my design it was appropriate to remove the margin from the <p> element.
From what I read the next best thing is giving the parent a tiny margin of it's own.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your styles:

```
#page p{ margin-top: 0; }
```

Comment: oh its been answered so fast crap

Comment: I know, but the answer is not really solving the cause, more the remedy.
Also, is the spacing of your answer deliberatly?

Comment: i just tested that and it really works oh and a lot of people gave the same answer really

Answer (score 0):

Yep there will be a gap at the top, because paragraph leaves some space before and after. The following removes the space try it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <title>Test Lay-Out</title>                     
                <style>
                        html{
                                overflow: auto; /*for IE*/
                                height: 100%;
                        }

                        body{
                                background-color: orange;
                                margin: 0;
                                height: 100%;
                        }
                        #page{
                                background-color: green;
                                height: 100%;
                                margin-bottom: -50px;
                        }
                        #page p.first{
                                margin-top:0;
                        }
                        #footer{
                                background-color: red;
                                height: 50px;
                        }
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="page">
                 <p class="first">test</p>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">footer</div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element?

Comment: That would .. hide the overflow. I don't think that's what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Are you sure? It actually makes the paragraph go fully inside the parent element; margin and all.

Comment: This could be true in the demo case, but it would also hide the overflow. And that's not something I want. In the real site, my content may be much bigger then the word "test"

Comment: How about overflow: auto; instead?